# Merging 2 models for an each statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 models. One is an event tracker for page views, the other is a model for search history.

I need to provide notifications which bind both of these together and then sort them by created_at through an each statement.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I think you need associations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: You need to  1) add some more detail of your setup 2) explain exactly what you are trying to do ("provide linear notifications" means nothing to me) 3) try to do it and then come here with a specific bug, rather than "I don't know where to start".  If you don't know where to start, then start by reading about Rails.

Comment: @RAJ How can this be achieved without model associations?

Comment: @MaxWilliams No problem, just point me in the right direction if you get the chance. It's like finding a needle in a haystack with the rails docs.

Comment: Just google some rails tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort an array which contains objects of multiple types. Try the following:

```
(ModelA.all + ModelB.all).sort_by(&:created_at)
```

Assuming you just need the sorting, you can reduce memory consumption by adding a select function to the query. You can append any other fields you need access to after the :created_at property.

```
(ModelA.all.select(:created_at) + ModelB.all.select(:created_at).sort_by(&:created_at)
```